# Add assignees to a project in youtrack

Tags: youtrack

We wish to create a custom role for a YouTrack project whose members cannot add or delete any issues but can be assigned an issue.

There are 28 distinct permissions for YouTrack that can be granted when creating a role.

Which of these get the user having this role into the assignee list for that project?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the list of permissions for the predefined "Developer" role, that is meant for assignees of the issue: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/7.0/Default-Roles.html?search=role#d26854e213 . I'd recommend to use it as a reference for the permissions' list, without including "Create issue" or "Delete issue" permissions.